# What is the recommended ordering of an AJAX load and history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

For instance, in jQuery, setting up a link to load something into a region, should I load the content before calling history.pushState?

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('#region').load('regionContent', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, 'newUrl');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Or should I load the content after calling history.pushState?

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, 'newUrl');
    $('#region').load('regionContent');
    return false;
});
```

The former seems preferable to me, because I feel the URL shouldn't change until the content does, but I've seen the latter more often (e.g. https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider), so I'm wondering which is considered best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With both your examples, when the user hits the back button the content isn't going to change! As you haven't got anything inside your state change handler.

Essentially you'll want to do this:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    History.pushState(null,null,'newUrl');
});
$('body').bind('statechange',function(){
    $('#content').load(History.getState().url);
});
```

This will make it when you click a link, the state of your page will change, and that given the state of your page has changed, it will load in the new content. Hitting the back button in your browser, will also cause the state to change, and thus load in your new content.

**Now here I have used [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)'s `statechange` and `History.getState().url` instead of the native `popstate` and `State.url` as different browsers will fire the state change event at different times.** For instance safari will the state change event at page load, where chrome and firefox don't - causing in safari your content to load twice. History.js provides a consistent API across all browsers, and if you wish even HTML4 browsers by falling back to hashes.

Comment: If I understand this implementation correctly, your answer implies that the history should be pushed before the content loads.  Is there any particular reason why this is preferable, other than uniformity of implementation (i.e. content is loaded in response to and only in response to a single event)?

Comment: Also, pushing history before loading content wouldn't work in the more general case, in which the URL to push must be determined on the server (e.g. POST-REDIRECT-GET with validation -- if validation succeeds, then push new URL, and if it fails, then don't push any URL).

Comment: I tend to feel that updating the state first, then loading in the content is the way to go as this is the way the web has worked for the past 20 years and intended to work. You navigate to a new page, the state changes, you load in the new content. Be it that content may be an error page. For instance, if I change my state to a page that doesn't exist, I would expect the content to become a 404 for the non existing state - rather than showing an error on the current working state.